# How do I specify compiler flags in a requirements.txt for pip?

Tags: pip, requirements.txt

(this is a self-answer, so dont rush into answering, but I will accept better suggestions later)

Assume that I need to specify some compiler flags to get `pip` to install a package to install successfully.

I'll take the example of pygraphviz, which needs to be told where to find some C language source files.

```
pip install pygraphviz
Collecting pygraphviz
....
      pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.c:3020:10: fatal error: 'graphviz/cgraph.h' file not found
      #include "graphviz/cgraph.h"
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      1 error generated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
```

It failed, as expected.  After looking around, I found that it was easy fix:  find the appropriate files (in *my case*, typically installed when installing graphviz) and point pip to it.

```
pip install pygraphviz --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-I/usr/local/Cellar/graphviz/8.0.1/include" --global-option="-L/usr/local/Cellar/graphviz/8.0.1/lib"
```

This works.  But how do I tell a requirements.txt file about those flags?

From the [pip docs, Per-requirement options](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/requirements-file-format/#per-requirement-options):

> Per-requirement options
>
> New in version 7.0.
>
> The options which can be applied to individual requirements are:
>
> --global-option
>
> --config-settings
>
> --hash (for Hash-checking Mode)

But that's all there is and I didn't see any examples.  Looking at the docs for the requirements format, it mostly talks about versioning qualifiers, not about build options.

Answer (score 0):

So, the funny thing is that, you just add them, **as you've typed them in the shell**, to the requirements file.

```
$pip install -r requirements.pygraphviz.globaloptions.txt 
WARNING: Implying --no-binary=:all: due to the presence of --build-option / --global-option / --install-option. 
Consider using --config-settings for more flexibility.
Collecting pygraphviz==1.11
  Using cached pygraphviz-1.11.zip (120 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Installing collected packages: pygraphviz
  Running setup.py install for pygraphviz ... done
Successfully installed pygraphviz-1.11
```

###### requirements.pygraphviz.globaloptions.txt:

```
pygraphviz==1.11 --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-I/usr/local/Cellar/graphviz/8.0.1/include" --global-option="-L/usr/local/Cellar/graphviz/8.0.1/lib"
```

Now, things to keep in mind.  pip is chatty about its opinion of `--global-options`.  And if you somehow misstyped something the error might look much the same, as if your global options had been ignored.  In my case, I had used an older version of graphviz, `2.50.0` and neglected to update requirements.txt to point to `8.0.1`.

So, by scanning the top of the output - pip complaining - and the end - clang erroring,  it looked as if the option specifier was being ignored.  It wasn't and once I got the correct flag configured, it worked just fine.  I just didn't expect to just work by dropping the command line flags into requirements.txt but it did.